# Understanding a proposition of topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

- For any $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, there is an open set $U\subseteq X$ such that if $V\subseteq X$ is open then $V\subseteq U$. Such a $U$ is necessariliy unique.

I didn't understand this proposition such that why is this important and necessariliy unique? Can you explain?

Comment: important in terms of what?

Comment: @KennyLau Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain English, the proposition states that every subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ contains some "maximal" open set, in the sense that every open subset of $X$ must be contained in that maximal open set.  This is important because this maximal open subset of $X$ (the interior of $X$) generalizes the concept of the interior of an interval (particularly if we assume that $X$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but a more abstract topological space).

Uniqueness is not too difficult to show:  just let $U$ be the union of all of the open sets in $X$.  That is, define
$$ U := \bigcup_{\substack{V \subseteq X \\ V\text{ is open} }} V.$$
$U$ is a union of open sets, hence must be open, and each set in the union is contained in $X$, so $U$ must be a subset of $X$.

To show uniqueness, suppose that $U'$ is an open subset of $X$ such that $V \subseteq U'$ for all $V\subseteq X$ with $V$ open.  Since $U'$ is an open subset of $X$, it must be one of the set in the union defining $U$, and so $U' \subseteq U$.  On the other hand, $U$ is an open subset of $X$, and so by the construction of $U'$, we have $U \subseteq U'$.  Thus $U = U'$, which gives uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for answer.,

Answer (score 2):

Take the union of all open sets contained in $X$. It is an open set because arbitrary union of open sets is an open sets (the second axiom of topology), and any open set contained in $X$ would be contained in the union.

Comment: Okey, you are right. But, why $U$ is necessariliy unique?

Comment: @Kahler Because it is the union of all open sets contained in $X$.

Comment: Suppose there were another such set. But it would be contained in the set given in this answer, which contradicts the maximalist assumption about the second set.

Comment: @KennyLau Okey, thanks.